# Best Way to Append data from json api React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In Homescreen, I am fetching data from json api and appending to data state variable. Each api call give 10 times. But the problem is, After 50 - 60 items app becomes very slow (even mobile freeze for 1-2 minutes). When I try to figure out the problem, and consoling each iterating of items, I seen the unnecessary re-renders while fetching to appending data to "setData" state. Look at the detailed problem below:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';

const API_URL = 'https://my-api-url.com/data';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      setData(jsonData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const loadMoreData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      setData([...data, ...jsonData]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      />
      <Button title="Load more" onPress={loadMoreData} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: @DươngThái, no it will not. `onPress={loadMoreData}` is pretty much ok.

Comment: Try the first suggestion in [this article](https://dev.to/erdenezayaa/react-native-optimizing-flatlist-performance-31k) and memoize your list item. By default, re-rendering is determined by shallow comparing the props. Your list item's prop is `item` itself, which is an object re-created each time `loadMoreData` is called. So they are never the same. You can try memo your list item with a [custom comparison function](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo#specifying-a-custom-comparison-function).

Answer (score 1):

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, dispatchData] = useReducer((state, actionData) => ([...state, ...actionData]), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      dispatchData(jsonData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const loadMoreData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      dispatchData(jsonData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = useCallback(({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      />
      <Button title="Load more" onPress={loadMoreData} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

That should be enough.